# How to determine this kind of vector?

Tags: java, jmonkeyengine

Take a look at the picture.

[image]

I've got a camera(brown) and its ray(red). As I know ray has a direction and unlimited length(if you don't set it yourself). But now I need to determine ray's vector that starts at camera point and ends when it crosses a floor. How can I do that?

Comment: there are many rays that cross a floor, which one do you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you know the ray direction, otherwise there are infinite rays that cross the floor. It crosses the floor when your camera pos (x,y,z) offset by a scaled ray direction k*(a,b,c) has zero height, so:

y + k*b = 0 => (we only care about the y component)
k = -y/b

so the vector that you need to add to the camera is

(-y/b)*(a,b,c)

Of course, it goes without saying that you need to check for special case when b == 0, where the ray is parallel to the xz plane, so it will never cross it, unless on it (y==0)

Comment: Is there a mistake? Why k was -y/b and then became b/y?

Comment: duh, thanks, my bad, fixed it. it should stay -y/b.

Answer (score 0):

The equation of the ray is `p = camerapos + t*ray` which is 3 equations (after splitting it up the coordinates):

```
p.x = camerapos.x + t*ray.x
p.y = camerapos.y + t*ray.y
p.z = camerapos.z + t*ray.z
```

then we know we want the point with `p.y = 0` so lets fill it in:

```
0 = camerapos.y + t*ray.y
t = -camerapos.y / ray.y
```

then just fill in the `t` in the first equation: `p = camerapos + (-camerapos.y / ray.y)*ray`